# Tastypie: How can I create an "abstract" ModelResource class with a Meta class

Tags: django, tastypie

Using [django-tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/toc.html) I'd like to create a child class of `ModelResource` to define some common things, which all my other API resource classes would inherit from. e.g.:

```py
class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = APIAuthorization()
        always_return_data = True

    # Some other common methods here


class UserResource(MyModelResource):
    class Meta(MyModelResource.Meta):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
```

However, if I do this, I get the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ModelResource (MyModelResource) requires Meta.object_class or Meta.queryset

So I *must* set `object_class` or `queryset` in `MyModelResource.Meta`, even though it's a kind of 'Abstract' class.

I can set `abstract = True` in `MyModelResource.Meta`, and this works, so long as I remember to set `abstract = False` in every one of its child classes.

Is there a better way to do this?